# How to sync Oracle database with SQL Server database other than linked server and SSIS..?

Tags: sql-server, database, oracle, synchronization

We have an Oracle database for some third party application. But I want sync some data from there to our application which is using a SQL Server database.

Currently using linked server and a SQL Serve Job which will run once every hour, so that data will get refreshed in the SQL Server database. But now we need live sync i.e. when something changes in the Oracle database, those changes need to be synced instantaneously with SQL Server rather than waiting for the SQL Server job to run.

So how can I achieve this? Is there any third party tools (cheap and best in terms of pricing, or if it's open source then good) which will detect and do the changes when changes happen in Oracle database?

Comment: If you want instantaneous, it sounds like you are talking about a two-phase commit protocol. What that means is that when you make a change in Oracle, the change happens in SQL Server too, **within the same transaction**. Now, what happens if the SQL Server database is unavailable or the network is down...?

Comment: @BobC--No..like i am having one .net app where i am using SQL db for that,and master data will come from Oracle Db(i.e like Name,Age,Address..etc).So if some thing changes in Oracle Db( like address and all in above case..) the same should reflect in SQL Db's master data instantaneously...If SQL goes down,when it's up again all the remaining changes should be taken place..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at Oracle Data Integrator.

See: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/rittman-odi-099646.html

It has an example doing exactly what you want.